# Lua - Txt file path

Tags: file, lua

I need to write on a .txt file using Lua. I know everything but not locate my file first. Let's say it is on Desktop (`C:\Users\NameGoesHere\Desktop\file,txt`), how do I locate it first? Before writing something to it, `file:write("Example")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try I like this one 
Change **,** to **.**

```
function filewrite(filename, filetext)
local file = io.open("C:\\Users\\NameGoesHere\\Desktop\\file.txt", "w" )
file:write(filetext)
file:close()
end
```

In Windows, you need to use double backslashes(\) for paths.

Comment: I've seen it and tried using C:\Users\NameGoesHere\Desktop instead of "w" but didn't work :/